# noConflict is not working in any way i tried

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, compatibility, prettyphoto

Making site with bootstrap carousel that works with jQuery v.2.1.4 and prettyPhoto gallery that works with jQuery v.1.7.1. Cant find solution to my problem, noConflict is not working for me - here is the code and how I tried to launch js files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv= "X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/galleryScript.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


</head>
<body> 
            <% include partials/template/header.ejs %> 
        <div class="mainMargin">
            <% include partials/template/nav.ejs %>
            <% include partials/template/slider.ejs %>
            <% include partials/content/main.ejs %>
        </div>
            <% include partials/template/footer.ejs %> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code of js that activeate plugin:

```
var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{


    function lightboxPhoto()
    {

        jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            animationSpeed: 'fast',
            slideshow: 1000,
            theme: 'facebook',
            show_title: false,
            overlay_gallery: false
        });

    }

    if(jQuery().prettyPhoto)
    {

        lightboxPhoto();

    }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using prettyPhoto with just jQuery v.2.1.4?

Comment: it was the first think i did))) first was only one jQuery version, than i thought to use two with noConflict, but it didnt wiork, Im using nodeJs, maybe it could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have found a solution, just changed places of js files loading, now how it looks like:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/galleryScript.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scroll.js"></script>
```